# Deallocated reference from UITableCell subview

Tags: ios

In one of my `UIViewControllers`, I have a `UITableView`, which only has two rows and both are always visible on screen.  This is a table view historically (another developer did it this way - and I'm not stuck with it).  Beause both rows of the table are always visible, when my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, I create one of the cells from a XIB and store a reference to one of the subviews (`UITextView`).  When I need to get hold of the text from that `UITextView`, I simply use the local reference.  This works fine - most of the times.

In one particular case, I navigate to another `UIViewController` from this one (using `pushViewController:animated`).  That new view controller uses quite a bit of memory, so internally iOS deallocates the table row from the first view controller (it's not visible any more, because another view controller is active) - and on my return to the first view controller it simply calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again.  When that row gets released, naturally the reference I stored internally is no longer valid - and if I try to use it, the app crashes ("selector sent to deallocated instance").

My question is: how can I catch when iOS internally releases the table cell so that I could set my reference to `nil` to be re-assigned at a later time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only way I found to deal with this issue is to include

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning;
```

callback and set the references to `nil` there.  Not sure if this is the best way of dealing with the situation, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5.0+, the easiest solution is to use a `__weak` reference to the text field. It will get set to `nil` automatically when the object is deallocated.

In earlier iOS versions, there is no simple solution. You could subclass `UITextField` or `UITableViewCell`, override the `release` or `dealloc` method in your subclass and from there send a notification that tells your view controller about the event. But it sounds like a pretty obscure hack to me. Better make sure that your reference is always valid – by setting it to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` and recreating it later when needed.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, the app has to work on iOS 3.2 and up, so `__weak` isn't going to help here.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS MVC world, you generally shouldn't rely upon retrieving data from UITextView for purposes outside of the view in question, anyway. You never know what the OS is going to do with a view when you go to other views. You'd probably want to store that string from your UITextView in some object that is either passed to those view controllers, accessible to the other view controllers (e.g. a singleton or a property of your app delegate), or stored in some persistent storage.

As an aside, even if the view is released because of low memory conditions, or if the cell is dequeued because you're using the same cell identifier in your other tableviews, its view controller stays around, so you don't need to worry about losing any properties you set in there unless you explicitly do something in didReceiveMemoryWarning to release it.